# NULL value when trying to get an author name of created subcategory using relations on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to print which user is an author of a subcategory but when I do dd(). I get a NULL value.

---

**User model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

**Category model:**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Subcategory Model:**

```
class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Function where I want to print an author of subcategory.**

```
public function show(Category $category)                                                    
{                                                                                   
    $subcategories = $category->subcategory->user->name;                                               
    dd($subcategory);                                                                 
    return view('subcategories', compact('subcategories '));
}
```

DD output: NULL also when I do `dd($category)` In "relations" i can see my "subcategory" but there is not "user" relation anywhere. Please help :/

**Migrations:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Requests:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ItemRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
@foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
 <li>{{$subcategory->user->name}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Category` model defines the relation as `subcategories`, but you are calling `$category->subcategory`. Instead, call the relation as you have it defined:

```
$subs = $category->subcategories;
```

Also, since the relation is one to many, you will need to loop through each subcategory in order to retrieve the user. Example:

```
$user_names = array();
foreach ($subs as $s) {
    $user_names[] = $s->user->name
}
dd($user_names);
```

Or, get the nth subcategory, etc.:

```
dd($category->subcategories->first()->user->name);

//Or

dd($category->subcategories->last()->user->name);

//Etc.
```

**Edit:**

Change your show method to this:

```
public function show(Category $category)                                                    
{                                                                                   
    $subcategories = $category->subcategory;                                               
    dd($subcategories);

    return view('subcategories', compact('subcategories'));
}
```

If You are still unable to see the user relation in each subcategory, try it with this:

```
$subcategories = $category->subcategory()->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: Still getting null at dd() after changing. It has to be sth about defining relations.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!! It's working :) `$subcategories = $category->subcategory()->with('user')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

subcategory does not have a user() relationship, only category has.so the user's name would be:

`$category->user->name`

Comment: I've added
`public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }`
In my subcategory model but i get still null.

Comment: Also `$category->user->name` is null too.

Comment: category->subcategories is a collection, not a single object. you should use something like category->subcategories[0]->user->name

Comment: Yes I know but i want to later display in foreach loop values but id dd() is returning null something is wrong...

Comment: if you put dump in the for loop, would you still see null? Are you sure there is data in the database? has you set the foreign key names user_id and category_id?

Comment: I added migrations in post, yes the data is in the database

Comment: please complete your sample codes in the question, and also add your migration codes so we could help

Comment: just did that :)

Comment: foreach($category->subcategories as $sc){dump($sc->user)} dd(); what do you get?

Comment: `null`
`Too few arguments to function dd(), 0 passed in(...)`

Comment: when I do dd($category) In "relations" i can see my "subcategory" but there is not "user" relation anywhere. is this still true?

Comment: Yes It is. But when I do dd($subcategories) i see all of my subcategories but in relations: `#relations: []` and probably there shloud be 'user' also there should be 'user' when doing dd(category) but theres not dont know why...

Comment: are you sure you have added the user() function to subcategory? I still do not see it in the question. and what databse do you use?

Comment: Yes, I've eddited my question and it looks 100% same like my code.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server @FatemehMajd